# $g(x,y,t) = f(x+yt,y,t)$ what is $\partial_t g$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

This is a simple question in multivariable calculus, but it confuses me.

Say that $f \in C^2\left(\Bbb{R}^d \times \Bbb{R}^d \times [0,T]\right)$ and it satisfies a PDE, such as
\begin{equation*}
\partial_tf(x,y,t) + \Delta_xf(x,y,t) + \Delta_yf(x,y,t) = h(x,y,t)
\end{equation*}
where $h \in C^0\left(\Bbb{R}^d \times \Bbb{R}^d \times [0,T]\right)$.

Define $g(x,y,t) = f(x+yt,y,t)$.

What PDE does $g$ satisfy?
Isn't this question ambiguous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the equation between $f$ and $g$ : 
$$f(x,y,t)=g(x-yt,y,t)$$
Then using the chain rule, you can express any derivatives of $f$ using the derivatives of $g$ :
$$\partial_t f=-y\partial_x g+ \partial_t g$$
(EDIT : $\partial_3 f=-y\partial_1 g+ \partial_3 g$)

Then inject it in the PDE of $f$. (You can compute in the same way Laplacians and higher derivatives using the first equality)

This works because you have $g=f\circ h$, with $h$ being a linear and invertible transformation, and thus a diffeomorphism (so basically what I did to get the first equation is composing your expression by $h^{-1}$) : $$f=g\circ h^{-1}$$ It might not have worked if $h$ was not invertible (because then, you can't get derivatives of $f$ from $g$).

Comment: Maybe write partial derivatives of $f,g$ using numbers instead of variables.  When talking about $g(x-yt,y,t)$, you may want to indicate the partical derivative of $g$ with respect to its second variable.  Or you may want to indicate the partial derivative of $g(x-yt,y,t)$ with respect to the variable $y$.  They are not the same thing:
$$
\partial_y g(x-yt,y,t) = -tg_1(x-yt,y,t) + g_2(x-yt,y,t)
$$
One small step to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks @GEdgar for this elucidation. It cleared my confusion. Nihl, also thanks, putting it more abstractly also makes it clearer, although a but longer.

Comment: @GEdgar : I see your point. I wanted to stay consistent with OP notation : for me $\partial_t g$ indicates the partial derivative of the function $g$ in respect to its third variable (since it was defined as $t$ by the OP), not the partial derivative of the expression $g(x-yt,y,t)$. I wanted to avoid introducing different notation from what Andrea used, but if it seems clearer to her to indicates partial derivative with ordinal indices...